# Magento 2 : Get product name using mysql query

Tags: magento2, database, sql

I am using Magento ver. 2.4.2

Is their any way we can get product attributes by id
using mysql query ?

I also need some custom attributes for product in same query

THE BELOW SQL QUERY WORKS BUT GET ONLY NAME ATTRIBUTE
I NEED OTHER ATTRIBUTES ALSO

```
select
 nametable.value as product_name,
 parent.type_id as product_type, parent.sku as sku,
 child.type_id as child_product_type, child.sku child_sku
from catalog_product_entity as parent
join catalog_product_relation as link
    on link.parent_id = parent.entity_id
join catalog_product_entity as child
    on child.entity_id = link.child_id
join catalog_product_entity_varchar as nametable ON nametable.row_id = parent.entity_id
AND nametable.store_id = 0
AND nametable.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id
  FROM eav_attribute
  WHERE attribute_code = 'name'
    AND entity_type_id =
      (SELECT entity_type_id
       FROM eav_entity_type
       WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
where parent.sku = 'P22756' limit 1
```

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: do you want to get the product name based on id using MySQL query?

Comment: Yes name & few custom attributes, that's it

Comment: not getting how to fetch

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: why using query not model?

Comment: I have such requirement that's why

Answer (score 0):

hey Try out below Query.

```
<?php 
$tableName = "catalog_product_entity";
$productId = 13;
$storeId = 0;

$sql = "SELECT ce.sku, ea.attribute_code,
                    CASE ea.backend_type 
                        WHEN 'varchar' THEN ce_varchar.value 
                        WHEN 'int' THEN ce_int.value 
                        WHEN 'text' THEN ce_text.value 
                        WHEN 'decimal' THEN ce_decimal.value 
                        WHEN 'datetime' THEN ce_datetime.value
                    END AS VALUE
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT cpe.sku, eas.entity_type_id, cpe.entity_id
                        FROM ". $tableName ." AS cpe, eav_attribute_set AS eas
                        WHERE cpe.entity_id = ". $productId ." AND cpe.attribute_set_id = eas.attribute_set_id
                    ) AS ce
                LEFT JOIN eav_attribute AS ea
                    ON
                    ce.entity_type_id = ea.entity_type_id
                LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ce_varchar
                ON
                    ce.entity_id = ce_varchar.entity_id AND ea.attribute_id = ce_varchar.attribute_id AND ea.backend_type = 'varchar' AND ce_varchar.store_id = $storeId
                LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS ce_int
                ON
                    ce.entity_id = ce_int.entity_id AND ea.attribute_id = ce_int.attribute_id AND ea.backend_type = 'int' AND ce_int.store_id = $storeId
                LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_text AS ce_text
                ON
                    ce.entity_id = ce_text.entity_id AND ea.attribute_id = ce_text.attribute_id AND ea.backend_type = 'text' AND ce_text.store_id = $storeId
                LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal AS ce_decimal
                ON
                    ce.entity_id = ce_decimal.entity_id AND ea.attribute_id = ce_decimal.attribute_id AND ea.backend_type = 'decimal' AND ce_decimal.store_id = $storeId
                LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_datetime AS ce_datetime
                ON
                    ce.entity_id = ce_datetime.entity_id AND ea.attribute_id = ce_datetime.attribute_id AND ea.backend_type = 'datetime' AND ce_datetime.store_id = $storeId;";
```